# Specgram is not calculated for the given signal

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot specgram for some specific signal, but what I get is just a blank plot:

[image]

I have no idea why is that. Here is my code which I used to plot the signal and the specgram itself:

```
import pylab as py

'''
PLOT SIGNAL

Additional info about the signal:
Sampling frequency = 1024.
Total samples = 1127.
'''
ax1 = py.subplot(2, 1, 1)
py.plot(np.arange(np.size(signal)), signal)

'''
PLOT SPECGRAM
'''
py.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = py.specgram(signal, NFFT=1024, Fs=1024, noverlap=900,
                                cmap=py.cm.gist_heat)
py.show()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should include everything and make your code unambiguous ... what is `py`?  From the syntax it looks like you've somehow imported `pyplot` twice, once as `py` and once as `plt`.

Comment: Also, think about why you are using `sharex`.  Do you understand why you expect the x-axis to be the same?  If you're just going from the specgram demo, you should try to understand *why* the things in the demo work, not just blindly apply them everywhere.

Comment: I just want specgram to be calculated for a single vector, one-dimensional signal, which in this case is consisted of 1127 float numbers, and to be expressed in the same x-axis as the signal i.

Comment: If you comment out all of the lines except the imports and the last two (just plot the specgram), do you see a valid plot?

Comment: I think I made my question much more clear now. I just plot the 1D vector on one plot, and now I tried to plot its specgram on the other plot. Unfortunately, there is just blank field.

Comment: Don't share the axis, try ```py.subplot(2, 1, 2)```.

Comment: I want to draw a spectrogram for the frequency spread over the timeline. Simple ploting it will not result in what I wrote above.

Comment: @bluevoxel Why did you choose NFFT=1024 when you only have 1127 samples?  Specgram calculates the spectrum in a sliding window, essentially, so because NFFT is almost as large as your data, you only end up with a couple of points in the x direction.  Without your data it's impossible to verify, but I'll bet that if you change NFFT to 64 or 256, you'll see more.

Answer (score 0):

To share the x axis, you should scale it to time instead of sample number. As @Ajean suggested, changing the number of samples in each periodogram allows *fuller coverage*.

First some fake data (2048 samples):

```
a = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi,2048)
b = np.linspace(0, 23*np.pi,2048)
s1 = np.sin(a)
s2 = np.sin(a*2)
s3 = np.cos(b)
s4 = np.cos(b*2)
s5 = np.sin(b)
signal = s1+s2+s3+s4+s5
```

Then an x axis representing time (sample rate = 200 sa/S)

```
fs = 200
x = np.arange(2048) / fs
```

These plots use time for the x axis - the specgram needs to be *informed* of the sample rate (`Fs`). Each plot has this in common:

```
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex = ax)
```

`
**NFFT = 1024**

```
spectrum, freqs, t, im = plt.specgram(signal, NFFT = 1024, noverlap = 512, Fs = fs)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

**NFFT = 256**

```
spectrum, freqs, t, im = plt.specgram(signal, NFFT = 256, noverlap = 128, Fs = fs)
```

[image]

**NFFT = 64**

```
spectrum, freqs, t, im = plt.specgram(signal, NFFT = 64, noverlap = 32, Fs = fs)
```

[image]

---

By decreasing the number of samples the specgram has more periodograms in the plot.  The x axis of the specgram represents the midpoint of each *segment* used to calculate the periodogram.

In the last plot, the last periodogram is centered at 10.08 seconds and includes data from 9.92-10.24 seconds.  The specgram stops *before* the time history because it has run out of data - the next periodogram would be centered at second 10.24 and would include data from 10.08-10.40 seconds, the last sample is at 10.24 seconds so another 64 sample periodogram cannot be made.

---

I imagine you can work out why your plot looks like it does.